# Javascript Regular Expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

Am working on password validation , I got stuck at looking for one RegEx ,

I need a RegEx which does not allow the password to start with numbers or which allows the password to start with alphabet .

I tried few RegEx like `[^0-9]` ,  `[ /[a-z][A-Z/g] ]` .

Kindly help me in this .

Comment: "which does not allow the password to start with numbers" --- please don't do that. Let your users make their own decision about what to start *their* passwords with. By adding some weird constraints you just make passwords less memorable for users.

Comment: but this is clients requirement .

Comment: Just because a client /asks/ for something doesn't mean you can't tell them they are an idiot (in nice words).

Answer (score 1):

Fairly simple, actually:

```
^[^0-9]
```

will make sure the first character is not a digit. But as zerkms notes in a comment already, you're reducing password entropy that way, thus making the system less safe, actually.

Comment: Error: SyntaxError: unterminated regular expression literal , i got this script error when i use the above RegEx .

Comment: can you help me in fixing this .

Comment: Make sure you're adding the slashes to indicate this is a regex. i.e., yourstring.match(/^[^0-9]/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the one you need:

```
^([^0-9]).*
```

**[Regex Demo](http://regexr.com?322ou)**

**EDIT:**

Javascript:

```
var regexmatch = /^([^0-9]).*/

if (regexmatch.test(YOUR_EXPRESSION)){ 
    // code stuff
}
```

Comment: Error: SyntaxError: unterminated regular expression literal

Comment: I just editted the answer..I me know if it works for you..@JeyRavi